# Running Storm in cluster, cleanup does not get called

Tags: java, apache-storm, topology

I have the following code for storm topology, which I am running on cluster:

```
TopologyBuilder builder = new TopologyBuilder();
builder.setSpout("word-reader", new WordReader());
builder.setBolt("word-normalizer", new WordNormalizer())
        .shuffleGrouping("word-reader");
builder.setBolt("word-counter", new WordCounter()).fieldsGrouping(
        "word-normalizer", new Fields("word"));
Config conf = new Config();
conf.put("wordsFile", args[0]);
conf.setDebug(false);
conf.put(Config.TOPOLOGY_MAX_SPOUT_PENDING, 1);
try {
    StormSubmitter.submitTopology("Test-topology", conf,
            builder.createTopology());
} catch (AlreadyAliveException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (InvalidTopologyException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

When I debug it, the following `cleanup()` method doesn't run in class `WordCounter`...

```
@Override
public void cleanup() {
    System.out.println("-- Word Counter --");
}
```

...and the topology doesn't finish running.

Comment: can you share the exception message??

Comment: So, I'm giving you the benefit of the doubt and removing the `insert code here` portion that I found while formatting your code.  Outside of that, this question is really incomplete - you should provide error conditions, stack traces, and what you really mean by "topology not finished" - I took a liberty and presumed "doesn't finish running", but I'd love to be certain.

Comment: I think you got the answer?

Comment: @abhi: According to his question. He is clear that his `cleanup()` method is not executing. So there will be no error, no stack traces, error conditions, etc..

Answer (score 3):

> **cleanup()**

Is called in local-mode when you `shutdown()` your `localcluster`. But not on your production cluster when `storm kill` is executed or it is removed from nimbus server (cleanup is never called on the production cluster, its only in local mode)

```
        // Keep commented if submitting to production cluster, since no
        // automatic shutdown is required on production cluster
        try {
            // Runs for specified number of ms after submitting topology on
            // local cluster and then resumes itself and shutdowns the
            // local cluster
            Thread.sleep(10000);
            objOfLocalCluster.shutdown();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // Prints a stack trace for this Throwable object on the error
            // output stream..
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

For more details: Go to this [docs](http://nathanmarz.github.io/storm/doc-0.8.1/backtype/storm/task/IBolt.html#cleanup%28%29)

---

Same thing happens with **`close()`** also (which is for spout) for more details on that check [here](http://nathanmarz.github.io/storm/doc-0.8.1/backtype/storm/topology/base/BaseRichSpout.html#close%28%29)

Comment: What would be the "ideal storm" way of cleaning the resources? JVM hooks?

Comment: @CᴴᴀZ did you find out how to cleanse the resources in bolt?

Comment: @AbdulSamad We utilized `finalize()` and `JVM shutdown hook` for cleaning up resources. Caveat: Hooks won't be executed under JVM override/crash scenario (such as system crash, kill command etc.)

Comment: Can you share some code examples? How you have used `finalize()` method and it belongs to which interface?

Answer (score 0):

Clean up is not called on the cluster.  Just localMode

http://groups.google.com/group/storm-user/browse_thread/thread/1a7b4998e6599f83/9683ed2b34e2c027?hl=en&lnk=gst&q=clean+up#9683ed2b34e2c027